# Probability density definition in Jaynes Probability Theory

Tags: density-function

I've a question for those who have read the book *Probability Theory of Jaynes*.
In the paragraph 4.5, where the author introduces probability density functions for the first time, I don't understand why he says that a finite number of propositions is all that is needed. In particular, it seems to me that for every real positive number $q$, the function that he calls $G(q)$ is effectively a new proposition for each $q$. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance and sorry if the question is too mirate, but it is intrinsically related to the probability intepretation given in that specific book.

Below is the paragraph in question:

[image]

Comment: I read this a little differently than you seem to.  After "... this is all we ever need in practice," Jaynes proceeds *nevertheless* to describe the construction of the usual CDF from an *uncountable* collection of "propositions."  I don't read it as claiming the CDF is determined by any finite set.  One might well question what Jaynes meant by "in practice," but that's a separate issue.

Comment: In every part of his book, Jaynes says that he wants to construct the whole probability theory only on finite sets. I'm nearly sure that he didn't want to describe the construction of the CDF from an uncountable collection of propositions.

Comment: Unless he resorted to nonstandard analysis, there's no avoiding it: you can't get from "finite and discrete" to "differentiable."  BTW, this passage is not about probability density functions: it's about CDFs.

Comment: My interpretation is that he seemingly wants to say that the probability of *any specific set of interest* can be computed based on a finite set of events of which the probabilities can be specified (chances are he wouldn't be interested in infinite unions of intervals that cannot be written as finite unions). That doesn't mean that the set of sets of potential interest is finite and that all these can be pieced together from a single finite set of events (such as half intervals).

Comment: What I wrote seems a bit circular though because it would imply that the "sets of interest" are just those that allow for such a computation...

Comment: I agree on your first sentence. So in this view, I have no problem at equation (4.54) if I have clear in mind that G(b) and G(a) are two notations to indicate two propositions (in other words, there isn’t any “G” function). The problem is in equation (4.55), when G is interpreted as a function, and so your first sentence is “violated”.

Comment: @Nameless But (4.55) is just a different mathematical way to write down the same probability. He says that you can compute (4.54) from just two propositions, and then he says that mathematically this amounts to (4.55), which may later help with certain computations, but doesn't contradict the statement before in any way.

Comment: I do have the book by the way and have read it quite some time ago, but looking a bit more around now doesn't give me any better idea.